# How to move lines up and down (change order) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with containing links and I want to change the order of them.

Can I automate this or do I have to do it manually?

My file is like this:

```
http;//filefactory.com/file/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//rg.to/file/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//clicknupload.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//ul.to/xxxxxxxx
http;//uptobox.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx

http;//filefactory.com/file/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//rg.to/file/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//clicknupload.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//ul.to/xxxxxxxx
http;//uptobox.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and so on........

I want to change order so that link order is like:

```
http;//rg.to/file/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//filefactory.com/file/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//clicknupload.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//uptobox.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//ul.to/xxxxxxxx

http;//rg.to/file/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//filefactory.com/file/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//clicknupload.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//uptobox.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx
http;//ul.to/xxxxxxxx
```

and so on ........

Comment: no solution ???

Comment: Since the link order in your original file follows the same pattern, I personally would record a macro in Excel to change the order of the links and run the macro on each of the paragraphs. It's still a bit manual and certainly not a suitable solution for 30,000 records but it may speed things up a little bit. Just a thought...

Answer (score 72):

The hot-keys to move lines up and down respectively are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>`and`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

[image]

Comment: That ridiculous animated gif is complete unnecessary ...and completely awesome +1 !!

Comment: There are plenty of easy tools that you can use to create a GIF like that almost as quickly as using the Snipping Tool :)

Comment: @Elijah : what tool did you use to make this gif?

Comment: @LongTTH Check out http://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: Note that this also works for multiple lines - just select the lines and move up/down to move the whole block around. Personally, I change the mapping to Alt+Up/Down to make it work the same as in eclipse.

Comment: @ElijahW.Gagne - Didn't know I wanted this until I found this post. Thank you.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Good tip. Can be found in Settings > Shortcut Mapper, look for "Move Up/Down Current Line", row 38/39. I changed to Ctrl+Alt+Shift to match Resharper in VS.